# Mysql query performance multiple and or conditions

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

I have this query in mysql with very poor performance.

```sql
select `notifiables`.`notification_id` 
from `notifiables` 
where `notifiables`.`notification_type` in (2, 3, 4) 
  and (    (    `notifiables`.`notifiable_type` = 16 
            and `notifiables`.`notifiable_id` = 53642) 
        or (    `notifiables`.`notifiable_type` = 17 
            and `notifiables`.`notifiable_id` = 26358) 
        or (    `notifiables`.`notifiable_type` = 18 
            and `notifiables`.`notifiable_id` = 2654)) 
order by `notifiables`.`id` desc limit 20
```

Is this query can be optimized in any way. Please help
This table has 2M rows. and taking upto 1-4 seconds in searching

[image: attached indexs of the table]

**Updated indexes and Explain select**

[image: updated indexes]

[image: explain select]

Comment: Try "union" instead of "or". I think it make your query faster.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Possible* solutions:

- Turning `OR` into `UNION` (see @hongnhat)
- Row constructors (see @Akina)
- Adding

  ```
    AND notifiable_type IN (16, 17, 18)
  ```
- Index hint.  I dislike this because it often does more harm than good.  However, the Optimizer is erroneously picking the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` (because of the `ORDER BY` instead of some filter which, according to the Cardinality should be very good.
- `INDEX(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id, id,  notification_id)` -- This is "covering", which can help because the index is probably 'smaller' than the dataset.  When adding this index, `DROP` your current `INDEX(notification_type)` since it distracts the Optimizer.
- `VIEW` is *very unlikely* to help.

**More**

Give this a try:  Add this to the beginning of the `WHERE`

```
WHERE notifiable_id IN ( 53642, 26358, 2654 ) 
  AND ... (all of what you have now)
```

And be sure to have an `INDEX` *starting with* `notifiable_id`.  (I don't see one currently.)

Comment: I guess dropping the index `INDEX(notification_type)` with using the `INDEX(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id, id,  notification_id)` is still not helping

Comment: @HarishJangra - Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I have updated the explain select and updated indexes in question.

Comment: @HarishJangra - I added something else to try.  By the way, does `notification_type` have any values other than (2, 3, 4)?

Comment: yes there are other values of `notification_type` and your update works the query optimized by `0.7 to 0.5 seconds` approx.

Answer (score 1):

Use the next syntax:

```sql
SELECT notification_id
FROM notifiables 
WHERE notification_type IN (2, 3, 4) 
  AND (notifiable_type, notifiable_id) IN ( (16, 53642), (17, 26358), (18, 2654) )
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Create index by `(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id)` or `(notifiable_type, notifiable_id, notification_type)` (depends on separate conditions selectivity).

Or create covering index (`(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id, notification_id)` or `(notifiable_type, notifiable_id, notification_type, notification_id)`).

Comment: @HarishJangra - Please report back on the performance.  Be sure to include the MySQL version (old versions will _not_ optimize that) and the `INDEX` that it used.  Terminology: `(1,2)` is a "row constructor".

Comment: @RickJames For this query to be optimized (use index) in 5.x we should combine conditions into one and check it against 9 combined row constructors.

Comment: @Akina - Why 9, not 3?  Also, I think that row constructors were first optimized in 5.7.3.  I have not heard that MariaDB has picked up that optimization yet.  (Hmmm...; I should check.)

Comment: @RickJames Because the combined condition will be `WHERE (notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id) IN ( (2, 16, 53642), (3, 16, 53642), ... , (4, 18, 2654) )`.

Comment: @Akina - Interesting.  I wonder if that helps or hurts.

Comment: @RickJames This allows to use the index instead of range scan by secondary condition.

Comment: @Akina I am using MySQL 5.7 on rds so maybe this doesn't change the performance significantly.

Comment: @RickJames I have tried with INDEX `(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id, notification_id)(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id, notification_id)` and `(notification_type, notifiable_type, notifiable_id)`  with mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You can make different kinds of "VIEW" from the data you want and then join them.

Comment: In MySQL, `VIEWs` are just syntactic sugar; they do not run any faster than the equivalent `SELECT`.  (Or at least I have never encountered an example of such.)